# How to start WinAppDriver programmatically in the remote machine

Tags: automation, winappdriver

My test setup consist of 2 windows machines, first one test runner which will have the my test code in c# and the second one test agent machine where winappdriver is installed along with application under test.

I would like to start the winappdriver in the test agent through the C# code and the code would run on the test runner. Also, I would like to close the winappdriver once test execution is over.

How this could be done? Appreciate any lead on this.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I am missing something here, but how does the accepted answer launch WinAppDriver in the REMOTE machine (i.e. Test Machine)? As far as I understand, that code will look for WinAppDriver in LOCAL machine (i.e. Test Runner) and will fail because WinAppDriver is not there. Did you manage to find an actual solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Java specific projects: You can Do it in following ways-
Assumin WinAppDriver is installed in default location-i.e. C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Application Driver

```
1st:
String command = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Application Driver/WinAppDriver.exe";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

2nd:
 String command = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Application Driver/WinAppDriver.exe";
 ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command).inheritIO();
 Process process = builder.start();

Dont forget to dispose it by-
        winDriver.close();
        winDriver.quit();

or for 2nd approach-
 process.destroy();
```

Convert them as part of you init or BeforeTest Methods as needed.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I am missing something here, but how does this launch WinAppDriver in the REMOTE machine (i.e. Test Machine)? As far as I understand, this code will look for WinAppDriver in LOCAL machine (i.e. Test Runner) and will fail because WinAppDriver is not there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [BeforeTestRun] attribute in your Test initialize class. Assuming the winappdriver is installed in the same path in the test machines. I use it in my azure agents

```
[BeforeTestRun]
        public static void TestSetup()
        {
            Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Application Driver\WinAppDriver.exe");
            Process.Start(@"Your application Path");
         
        }
```

After the test run, if you want to close the Winappdriver, you can use AfterTestRun Attribute. Basepage has the static instance of the WinappDriver

```
 [AfterTestRun]
        public static void TearDownReport()
        {
            BasePage.WindowsDriver.Close();
            BasePage.WindowsDriver.Dispose();            
        }
```

Comment: This also does not work for the purposes indicated in the question. This is not launching WinAppDriver in the REMOTE machine, but in the LOCAL machine instead.